# Dynamically loop through checkboxes and get their value and isChecked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I am dynamically printing out checkboxes depending on list from database, called in the code 'coachProperties'. Each coachProperty will get their own checkbox appended with the text which is unique.
I want to add this to another object 'properties'. Something like 'properties{text1 : "false, text2 : "true"} to then later on take it to server-side to do some filtering. I dont want any sumbit button since i want it to dynimcally update which i have js code for. All values in  'properties' will start with "false" which should update when checkbox is clicked. The problem is, sometimes when I uncheck a box it still displays as true and vice versa.

```
    <div data-id="coachPropertiesCheckbox">
                <% coachProperties.get('coachProperties').forEach(function (coachProperty) { %>
                    <div class="checkboxes">
                        <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-id="test" value="<%= coachProperty.text %>"> <%= coachProperty.text %>
                        </label>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                <% }); %>
            </div>
```

Js code:

```
function setProp(obj,prop,value){

            obj[prop] = value;

            };


            var properties = {};

            coachProperties.get('coachProperties').forEach(function (coachProperty) {

            properties[coachProperty.text] = "false";

            
         });


 view.$el.find('[data-id="coachPropertiesCheckbox"] div.checkboxes input').change(function () {


            var isCheckboxedChecked = view.$el.find('[data-id="test"]').is(':checked');

            var valueCheckbox = $(this).attr("value");



            setProp(properties, valueCheckbox, isCheckboxedChecked );



            $.each( properties, function( key, value ) {

                console.log( key + ": " + value );


                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     view.$el.find('div.checkboxes input').change(function (event) {

             var id = $(event.target).attr('data-id');

             if ($(event.target).prop('checked')) {

                 resultSetParameters.get('filter').coachProperties.push(id);

                 resultSetParameters.trigger('change');

             } else {

                 var index = resultSetParameters.get('filter').coachProperties.indexOf(id);

                 if (index > -1) {

                     resultSetParameters.get('filter').coachProperties.splice(index, 1);

                     resultSetParameters.trigger('change');

                 }

             }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` property to hold data that you would like to associate with the checkbox and do not use it to toggle `true` and `false`. Whether checkbox is checked or not, you can know from the `checked` property.

A piece of advice, most probably, you'll NOT want to use checkbox label same as `value` because values are for internal purpose, for any data manipulation, and labels have sole purpose of display in the UI.

Please try the following solution direction:

```js
$('.checkboxes input').on('change', (event) => {
  const checked = $(event.target).prop('checked')
  const value = $(event.target).prop('value')
  console.log(checked, ':', value)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1-id" value="checkbox-1" /><label for="checkbox1-id">Checkbox 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2-id" value="checkbox-2" /><label for="checkbox2-id">Checkbox 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3-id" value="checkbox-3" /><label for="checkbox3-id">Checkbox 3</label>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm the first line: $('.checkboxes input').on('change', (event) => {   returns this error message in the browser: Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Could that be a browser cache issue? It is working fine at my end in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Not likely, i always clear cache during web-development. Not sure where it comes from